# Where clause not select o count in in SQL Server CE

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have a problem in select the all count value list to table using SQL CE.

```
SELECT  Time AS Hour,Cast (COUNT(ReceivedTime)*1.0/(10)as decimal(16,2)) AS HourlyTotal 
    FROM tblTime 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblMessageReceived ON Time = ReceivedTime  
    WHERE ReceivedDateTime >= '2016-01-01'  AND ReceivedDateTime <= '2016-07-07' 
    GROUP BY Time
```

But it select the non zero count only. As the result table below.

[image: Result Table]

In here i want to select all Hour time with the 0 count values.

Comment: Put the conditions in the `ON` clause.

Comment: @FelixPamittan in there i used ON  Clause (ON Time = ReceivedTime ), But it not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause effectively turns your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. The solution is to put them in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT  
    t.Time AS Hour,
    CAST(COUNT(t.ReceivedTime)*1.0/(10) AS DECIMAL(16, 2)) AS HourlyTotal 
FROM tblTime t
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblMessageReceived tmr
    ON t.Time = tmr.ReceivedTime  
    AND tmr.ReceivedDateTime >= '2016-01-01'
    AND tmr.ReceivedDateTime <= '2016-07-07' 
GROUP BY t.Time
```

Note:

- Use a meaningful alias to improve readability.

Comment: Thanks @Felix Pamittan , Now it works fine. found the error                                                   "WHERE clause effectively turns your LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN".  Can you please explain the how it effects where clause.

Comment: In your original query, after the `JOIN` is performed, the non-matched rows will have a `NULL` value for `ReceivedDateTime`. These rows will then be eliminated by the `WHERE` clause.